# Complete Google Image search layout

Tags: image, search, layout

I have found a solution from http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/bNYBZX but it i incomplete.

```
<section class="image-grid">
  <div class="image__cell is-collapsed">
    <div class="image--basic">
      <a href="#expand-jump-1">
        <img id="expand-jump-1" class="basic__img" src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/fashion/1" alt="Fashion 1" />
      </a>
      <div class="arrow--up"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image--expand">
      <a href="#close-jump-1" class="expand__close"></a>
      <img class="image--large" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/fashion/1" alt="Fashion 1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I need to have a side gallery for images to load in the preview section on click just like google image search. Here is the image of what I want to do [Google Image search layout preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL5CB.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Did a codepen with the solution I wanted. http://codepen.io/bahiirwa/pen/BKmmzm

HTML

```
<section class="image-grid">
  <div class="image__cell is-collapsed">
    <div class="image--basic">
      <a href="#expand-jump-1">
        <img id="expand-jump-1" 
                 class="basic__img"
                 src="http://yourdigitalblend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DB_Team_Bio_jz.png" alt="Fashion 1">
      </a>
      <div class="arrow--up"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image--expand">
      <a href="#close-jump-1" class="expand__close"></a>
      <img class="image--large" 
           src="http://yourdigitalblend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DB_Team_Bio_jz.png" alt="Fashion 1">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image__cell is-collapsed">
    <div class="image--basic">
      <a href="#expand-jump-2">
        <img id="expand-jump-2" 
                 class="basic__img"
                 src="http://yourdigitalblend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DB_Team_Bio-ed.jpg" alt="Fashion 1">
      </a>
      <div class="arrow--up"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image--expand">
      <a href="#close-jump-2" class="expand__close"></a>
      <img class="image--large" 
           src="http://yourdigitalblend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/DB_Team_Bio-ed.jpg" alt="Fashion 1">
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</section>
```

CSS

```
html {box-sizing: border-box;}

*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

.image-grid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1310px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px 0;
}

.image__cell {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}

.image--basic {
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.basic__img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image__cell.is-collapsed .arrow--up {
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.image--large {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image__cell.is-collapsed .image--basic {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image__cell.is-expanded .image--expand {
  max-height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image--expand {
  position: relative;
  left: -5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .3s ease-in-out,
              margin-bottom .1s .2s;
  width: 500%;
}

.image__cell:nth-of-type(5n+2) .image--expand {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.image__cell:nth-of-type(5n+3) .image--expand {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

.image__cell:nth-of-type(5n+4) .image--expand {
  margin-left: -300%;
}

.image__cell:nth-of-type(5n+5) .image--expand {
  margin-left: -400%;
}

.image__cell:nth-of-type(5n+6) {
  clear: left;
}

.image__cell.is-expanded .arrow--up {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #222;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 2px auto 0;
}

.expand__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.expand__close:before {
  content: '×';
}

.expand__close:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

JS

```
var $cell = $('.image__cell');

$cell.find('.image--basic').click(function() {
  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.image__cell');

  if ($thisCell.hasClass('is-collapsed')) {
    $cell.not($thisCell).removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-collapsed').addClass('is-expanded');
  } else {
    $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
  }
});

$cell.find('.expand__close').click(function() {
  var $thisCell = $(this).closest('.image__cell');
  $thisCell.removeClass('is-expanded').addClass('is-collapsed');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you can query SerpAPI to get a JSON response.
Then you can easily loop over the images in the json.

https://serpapi.com/images-results

Comment: I was looking for a UI